# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() - NLP

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am trying to create a variable with the length of the text. I am using the code below:

```py
messages['length']=messages['Review Text'].apply(len)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fa1723bfb3a3> in <module>
----> 1 messages['length']=messages['Review Text'].apply(len)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check your data carefully. The message `"TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()"` leads me to believe at least one of your cells in `'Review Text'` is not a text value, but instead a float value.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a trivial example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'str': 'free peoples of middle earth'}])
```

Just call the method for getting the length of a string vector.

```
df['str'].str.len()

0    28
Name: str, dtype: int64
```

If you have non-string elements, then you either need to convert them to string using `astype(str)` before going for `Series.str` or if you have `NaN` then `fillna(0)` on the output column after getting the length, wherever you put it. Unless, of course, you don't want to fill them in with data, because the `NaN`s propogate.

**Edit.** The reason why you get the error saying that floats don't have a length is because you have `NaN` in your data. Eg

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'str': 'free peoples of middle earth'}, {'str': np.nan}])

df['str'].apply(lambda s: len(s))

... Traceback suppressed
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Note, however, that the `Series.str.len()` function deals with this:

```
df['str'].str.len()
Out[59]: 
0    28.0
1     NaN
Name: str, dtype: float64
```